# How can I solve the string expression in python?

Tags: python

```py
A= '5.5+6.5-8.5' 
Result =3.5

B='15.5+25.5-35.5'
Result =5.5
```

I tried few string method like `append` and `split`

Comment: do you want to add like doing the math them or append them like writing them out?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to evaluate a mathematical expression from a string you can use **eval** function

```
eval('5.5+6.5-8.5') # or eval(A)

eval('15.5+25.5-35.5') # or eval(B)
```

Answer (score -1):

That's how you append them, do the same to the B string.

```
print("A = 5.5 + 6.5 - 8.5 Result = 3.5")
```

Comment: Was your question answered?